# How to refresh the bootstrap multiselect checkbox and maintain original values of checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to refresh a bootstrap 3.0 multiselect control.
On refresh, I want to reset the checkboxes to its previous state when the partial view was first rendered

How can I achieve that?

I tried following approach but didn't get success.

1. Maintained hidden field for storing selected checkbox values once view
   was rendered.

   On Reset button click:

   2.1 Uncheck all checkboxes.
   2.2 Check only those checkboxes whose value I got from hidden field.

   ```
   j('#btnReset11').click(function () {            
           j("#divErrorMessage ul li").not(':first').remove();
           j("#divErrorMessage").hide();
           j("#divSuccessMessage").hide();

           j("#includeSelectAllOption").find("option").removeAttr("selected");
           j("#chkRoles ul li").removeClass("active");
           j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").removeAttr('title');
           j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").text('Select');

          var value = j("#selectedCheckboxes").val();
           valueItems = value.split(", ");
           for (var i = 0; i < valueItems.length; i++) {
               j('#' + valueItems[i]).attr('selected', 'selected');
               j("#chkRoles ul li input[value=" + valueItems[i] + "]").parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
               var title = j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").title;
               j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").removeAttr(title);
           }

           if (valueItems.length > 0) {
               j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").text(valueItems.length + ' selected');
           }
           else {
               j("#chkRoles .btn-group").find("button").text('Select');
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: How are the checkboxes getting the first state? Is a model being used based on a previous action, or is it a predefined selected state for the multiselect? Is __OnRefresh__ a button click and/or a page reload?

Comment: attr('selected', 'selected') is this to check the checkboxes? If so try .prop('checked', true) instead.

Comment: No. Its not working. Is there any solution for this in bootstrap? I mean, Is there any simpler way of calling bootstrap js functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    j(document.body).on('click', '#btnReset-Button', function () {        
    j("#divErrorMessage").hide();
    j(this).parents('.PopupModalClass').find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],select').each(function () {
        if (this.defaultValue != '' || this.value != this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
            setTimeout(function () {
                j('.PopupModalClass #multiSelectDropdown').multiselect('refresh');
            });
        } else { this.value = ''; }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please also add some context/ explanation?